# Passport.authenticate loops forever

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, passport.js

I am using Passport.js to connect my Node application to the Google+ API using a GoogleStrategy.
I call the auth/api route from my frontend (localhost:3000) to my server (localhost:5150).
My code gets to the route successfully and calls the passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email"] }) method but no action is performed. My frontend just waits endlessly for the Google callback but it never comes.

Why would this be happening?

My code:

```
export const authenticateUsingGoogle = (req, res) => {
  console.log(`authenticating using google`);
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "openid", "profile "] });
  console.log(`authenticated using google`);
};
```

I have seen two similar questions being asked on Stackoverflow but they have no answers:

[passport.authenticate() loads forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643264/passport-authenticate-loads-forever/71073904#71073904)

[Passport.authenticate() gets stucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974271/passport-authenticate-gets-stucks)

Answer (score 1):

`passport.authenticate` method returns a middleware for express. You need to use it as an argument for your express router.

Example:

```js
app.post('/login/password',
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "openid", "profile "] }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Your actual code.
  });
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/middleware/).

Comment: I included it. Still did not work.

Comment: Have you tried your setup with a different strategy, such as basic authentication? It's important to find the root cause of the problem, the google strategy, or the passport module itself.